# bootstrap collapse on specific break points

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can the toggle functionality on Bootstrap collapse accordion be disabled only on larger resolutions?

The goal is to have the accordion collapsed on small resolutions with the option to toggle states, and expanded on large resolutions with no option to toggle states. What would be the best way to use Bootstrap built in functionality to achieve this?

anyway to do this in vanilla js?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't vanilla js but as Bootstrap uses jQuery it is probably more convenient doing it this way.

You can achieve that by disabling the click event:

```
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e){
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {  
        e.stopPropagation();
    }    
});
```

You will also want to toggle the collapsed classes for accordion divs:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 768){  
        $('.panel-collapse').addClass('in');
    }
    if ($(window).width() <= 768){  
        $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
    }
});
```